# How to return only the changed resources in a collection using REST

Tags: rest, api-design

Let's say I'm designing a REST API that should return a list of an authenticated user's contacts

```
e.g. /users/me/contacts
```

To improve performance I'll return an ETag and provide this in future GET requests in the If-None-Match header. Assuming nothing has changed then the API will return a Not-Modified response.

However what happens when the list of contacts has changed? I don't want to return the entire collection again, just the new and modified items.

I could send a HEAD request, compare ETags and then send a subsequent GET request for the new items but this seems a bit wasteful.

I've just come across the If-Range header which looks like it might solve the issue but it seems to also require the Range header which is specified in bytes.

Do you think the If-Range header is the way to go or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

REST is about resources. If `/users/me/contacts` is the URL of a resource (list of contacts), it must always return the full representation of the resource state.

If you want to retrieve only those contacts that have changed, use a query parameter:

```
/users/me/contacts?newerThan=20130513124300
```

with `newerThan` the date the client last accessed the resource.

This would be RESTful since every different value of `newerThan` would form a different URL.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have an idea of what would happen if a record was deleted? would that be returned somehow in the "newerThan" data...?

Comment: @MeV perhaps you can just have a separate flag for is_deleted rather than actually deleting anything. The newerThan query param is nice, but it would be nice if following some standard like the If-Modified-Since header (but I prefer query param for this) so people know what to expect for names, formats, and how to deal with out of synch clocks.

Comment: Your answer is quite right, but why don't you use an UTC formatted timestamp instead of a numeric timestamp? That way you can handle timezones